# Multivalued copy field support in DSE SOLR

Tags: solr, cassandra, datastax-enterprise, datastax

I have a SOLR schema as following:

```
<field name="category_id1" type="integer" indexed="false" stored="true" />
<field name="category_id2" type="integer" indexed="false" stored="true" />
<field name="category_id3" type="integer" indexed="false" stored="true" />
<field name="category_ids" type="integer" multiValued="true" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
```

and a copy section:

```
<copyField source="category_id1" dest="category_ids" />
```

but whenever I tried to inject the data into DSE/Cassandra, I got this error

`InvalidRequestException(why:(Expected 4 or 0 byte int (14)) [diem][business][category_ids] failed validation)
me.prettyprint.hector.api.exceptions.HInvalidRequestException: InvalidRequestException(why:(Expected 4 or 0 byte int (14)) [diem][business][category_ids] failed validation)
Exception in thread "main" me.prettyprint.hector.api.exceptions.HInvalidRequestException: InvalidRequestException(why:(Expected 4 or 0 byte int (14)) [diem][business][category_ids] failed validation)
    at me.prettyprint.cassandra.service.ExceptionsTranslatorImpl.translate(ExceptionsTranslatorImpl.java:45)
    at me.prettyprint.cassandra.connection.HConnectionManager.operateWithFailover(HConnectionManager.java:264)
    at me.prettyprint.cassandra.model.ExecutingKeyspace.doExecuteOperation(ExecutingKeyspace.java:97)
    at me.prettyprint.cassandra.model.MutatorImpl.execute(MutatorImpl.java:243)
    at com.diem.db.crud.CassandraStorageManager.insertMultiColumns(CassandraStorageManager.java:197)
    at com.diem.db.dao.impl.AbstractDaoImpl.saveUUIDEntity(AbstractDaoImpl.java:47)
    at com.diem.db.dao.impl.BusinessDaoImpl.saveBusiness(BusinessDaoImpl.java:81)
    at com.diem.data.LoadBusinesses.execute(LoadBusinesses.java:187)
    at com.diem.data.LoadContent.run(LoadContent.java:121)
    at com.diem.data.LoadBusinesses.main(LoadBusinesses.java:45)
Caused by: InvalidRequestException(why:(Expected 4 or 0 byte int (14)) [diem][business][category_ids] failed validation)
    at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.Cassandra$batch_mutate_result.read(Cassandra.java:20833)
    at org.apache.thrift.TServiceClient.receiveBase(TServiceClient.java:78)
    at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.Cassandra$Client.recv_batch_mutate(Cassandra.java:964)
    at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.Cassandra$Client.batch_mutate(Cassandra.java:950)
    at me.prettyprint.cassandra.model.MutatorImpl$3.execute(MutatorImpl.java:246)
    at me.prettyprint.cassandra.model.MutatorImpl$3.execute(MutatorImpl.java:243)
    at me.prettyprint.cassandra.service.Operation.executeAndSetResult(Operation.java:103)
    at me.prettyprint.cassandra.connection.HConnectionManager.operateWithFailover(HConnectionManager.java:258)
    ... 8 more`

A copy into a multiValued solr.IntField (integer) isn't something special and we could do it before using DSE/SOLR. But I can't seem to get this work inside DSE/SOLR combination. Logically speaking, I can't see any reason why this fails, because DSE should not interfere with operation on `category_ids` field, which is used primarily for indexing. Does anyone see anything wrong with the situation? What could I do in this situation to prevent the validation error (***note***: I can't use a text/string type for `category_ids`)?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I could find out the problem, my CF has a `default_validation_class=BytesType`, so the multiValued field `category_ids` is validated using BytesType in DSE/Solr, which will cause the error. So unless I change my CF into CQL declaration using the type of `LIST<int>` and do not use Hector (at least for this CF), I won't be able to work with multiValued fields other than text/string fields in Solr.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand it correctly, you are using thrift tables, so you either declare the category_ids *column* as UTF8Type (the Solr field can be of any type), or you declare the category_ids Solr field as stored=false (in which case the copy field will not be stored, only indexed).

Let us know if any of the two works for you.